# Use curl and loop in shell script to through different jq values

Tags: bash, loops, curl, jira

I am using a curl command to get json data from an application called "Jira".

Stupidly (in my view), you cannot use the api to return more than 50 values at a time.

The only choice is to do it in multiple commands and they call this "pagination". It is not possible to get more than 50 results, no matter the command.

This is the command here:

```
curl -i -X GET 'https://account_name.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/project/search?jql=ORDER%20BY%20Created&maxResults=50&startAt=100' --user 'scouse_bob@mycompany.com:<sec_token_deets>'
```

This is the key piece of what I am trying to work into a loop to avoid having to do this manually each time:

```
startAt=100
```

My goal is to "somehow" have this loop in blocks of fifty, so, startAt=50 then startAt=100, startAt=150 etc and append the entire output to a file until the figure 650 is reached and / or there is no further output available.

I have played around with a command like this:

```
#!/bin/ksh
i=1
while [[ $i -lt 1000 ]] ; do
   curl -i -X GET 'https://account_name.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/project/search?jql=ORDER%20BY%20Created&maxResults=50&startAt=100' --user 'scouse_bob@mycompany.com:<sec_token_deets>'
   echo "$i"
  (( i += 1 ))
done
```

Which does not really get me far as although it will loop, I am uncertain as to how to apply the variable.

Help appreciated.

Comment: Pagination is pretty common in APIs, it avoid sending all data at once with the risk of loosing it all :)

Answer (score 1):

> My goal is to "somehow" have this loop in blocks of fifty, so, startAt=50 then startAt=100, startAt=150 etc and append the entire output to a file until the figure 650 is reached and / or there is no further output available.

The former is easy:

```
i=0
while [[ $i -lt 650 ]]; do 
   # if you meant until 650 inclusive, change to -le 650 or -lt 700 
   curl "https://host/path?blah&startAt=$i"
   # pipe to/through some processing if desired
   # note URL is in " so $i is expanded but 
   # other special chars like & don't screw up parsing
   # also -X GET is the default (without -d or similar) and can be omitted
   (( i+=50 ))
done
```

The latter depends on just what 'no further output available' looks like. I'd expect you probably don't get an HTTP error, but either a contenttype indicating error or a JSON containing either an end or error indication or a no-data indication. How to recognize this depends on what you get, and I don't know this API. I'll *guess* you probably want something more or less like:

```
curl ... >tmpfile
if jq -e '.eof==true' tmpfile; then break; else cat/whatever tmpfile; fi
# or
if jq -e '.data|length==0' tmpfile; then break; else cat/whatever tmpfile; fi
```

where `tmpfile` is some suitable filename that won't conflict with your other files; the most general way is to use `$(mktemp)` (saved in a variable). Or instead of a file put the *data* in a variable `var=$(curl ...)` and then use `<<<$var` as input to anything that reads stdin.

EDIT: I *meant* to make this CW to make it easier for anyone to add/fix the API specifics, but forgot; instead I encourage anyone who knows to edit.

You *may* want to stop when you get *partial* output i.e. if you ask for 50 and get 37, it may mean there is no more after those 37 and you don't need to try the next batch. Again this depends on the API which I don't know.